# 'succeed' and part of speech

Tags: parts-of-speech, understanding

I have the following sentence.

> I'm really excited to share with you some findings that really surprise me about what makes companies **succeed** the most, what factors actually matter the most for startup success.

And I don't understand which part of speech the word 'succeed' is.
If it's predicate then where is subject?

Comment: What does your dictionary say ?

Answer (score 6):

*Succeed* is an intransitive verb: it does not take an object. Its subject is *companies*.

> Horses run.
>   Men breathe.
>   Companies succeed.

These are all complete sentences.

In this sentence *succeed* is specifically an (unmarked) infinitive, the head of an infinitival clause which is the complement of the verb *makes*, understood in this construction (*MAKE SUBJ*<sup>ACC</sup> *VERB*<sup>INF</sup>) in a causative sense.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake in the question. I meant a subject.